# Spark DataFrame partition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

At present, I have a dataframe. I want to divide them into several independent dataframes and then process them in turn.

A spark datafame like :

```
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|            id|data_identifier_method|       start_time|         end_time|time_interval|             time|    value|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
|  fd784213423f|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|  fd784213423f|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|  fd784213423f|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
|  fd784213423f|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|  fd784213423f|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|  fd784213423f|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

then I want to divide it into four dataframes:

```
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|            id|data_identifier_method|       start_time|         end_time|time_interval|             time|    value|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

```
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|            id|data_identifier_method|       start_time|         end_time|time_interval|             time|    value|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|fd78sfsdfsd8vs|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

```
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|            id|data_identifier_method|       start_time|         end_time|time_interval|             time|    value|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|  fd784213423f|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|  fd784213423f|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|  fd784213423f|  algid1_set1_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

```
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|            id|data_identifier_method|       start_time|         end_time|time_interval|             time|    value|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|  fd784213423f|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|  fd784213423f|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|  fd784213423f|  algid2_set2_total...|20200903 00:00:00|20200903 00:00:10|            5|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

What should I do？

In other words, if I don't divide the original dataframe, how can I operate on these four items in the original dataframe?

Comment: What about using `filter`?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I would recommend you go through one of the many existing tutorials on basic dataframe operations. For example this one: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-scala.html

Comment: If you are still facing issues, come back here and show what you have tried and what is not working as expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using **NTILE**

NTILE is an Spark SQL analytic function. It divides an ordered data set into a number of buckets indicated by expr and assigns the appropriate bucket number to each row. The buckets are numbered 1 through expr. The expr value must resolve to a positive constant for each partition.

It will have a partition no (NTILE value ).  Now you can use filter to create no of data set specified in Ntile function .

Below  is dummy code .

```
val w = Window.orderBy("sum_val")
val resultDF = x.orderBy("sum_val").select( x("id"),x("sum_val"), ntile(4).over(w) )

+---+-------+-----+
| id|sum_val|ntile|
+---+-------+-----+
|  B|      3|    1|
|  E|      4|    1|
|  H|      4|    2|
|  D|     14|    2|
|  A|     14|    3|
|  F|     30|    3|
|  C|     34|    4|
+---+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score -1):

"I want to divide them into several independent dataframes and then process them in turn."

What are you actually trying to solve?  There's a bunch of ways to accomplish something similar depending on your requirements each with very different memory and performance characteristics.

1. use table partitioning.  All output files end up in the same folder path BUT there technically can be more then one file per partition.  Optionally sort by the partition column to minimizes the number of output files.

> dataframe.write.partitionBy("partition_col").parquet("s3://bucket/path/")

2. use HashAggregation to colocate all matching records into the same partition BUT multiple keys can end up in the same partition

> dataframe.repartition("partition_col")...

3. collect partition column values and then run independent jobs on each value.  This allows you to collect all into a single partition BUT this is much slower than the first two and involves rereading many records and also jams them into a single partition which can cause performance issues and memory issues.

```
val partitionColVals = dataframe.groupBy("partition_col").map(_.get(0)).collect
for(val partitionColVal <- partitionColVals){
  dataframe.where(col("partition_col" === lit(partitionColVal)).repartition(1)...
}

4.  Window functions - this is an SQL concept that allows you todo operations on sets of matching keys.  Kinda like a high powered group by.  This will depend on what you're trying todo.
```